# how to assign an R.drawable folder image to a Bitmap object

Tags: android, casting, bitmap, assignment-operator

How do I load an image of jpg or png type in the R.drawable folder of android into a Bitmap object?

```
Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap) putThisImageIntoBitmap(R.drawable.myimage);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you have to use the BitmapFactory class, then decode the resource file with the drawable's id and context's resources as parameters.

Sample:

```
putThisImageIntoBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),R.drawable.myimage));
```

- if your class extends an "Activity" class, you could just use "this" or "getApplicationContext()" method.
- the second parameter is the id of the drawable you want to get

Answer (score 1):

```
InputStream is = null;
Bitmap bmp = null;

is = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.myimage);
bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(),
            R.drawable.ic_launcher);
```

where `mContext` is current activity context.